# Nutch 2.3.1 in crawl Deep Web

Tags: solr, web-crawler, nutch, deep-web

i follow the tutorial from

1. Nutch Wiki "SetupNutchAndTor"(https://wiki.apache.org/nutch/SetupNutchAndTor)
2. Set up `nutch-site.xml`

   ```
     <property>
           <name>http.proxy.host</name>
           <value>127.0.0.1</value>
           <description>The proxy hostname.  If empty, no proxy is used.
           </description>
     </property>

       <property>
           <name>http.proxy.port</name>
           <value>8118</value>
           <description>The proxy port.</description>
       </property>
   ```

but still crawl nothing from the .onion link and not indexed into Solr. Anyone know what is the problem?

Answer (score 0):

Anything in the logs?

FYI with StormCrawler you can use a SOCKS proxy directly thanks to [this commit](https://github.com/DigitalPebble/storm-crawler/issues/530)

You'd need to use OKHTTP for the protocol implementation and configure it like this

> http.protocol.implementation: "com.digitalpebble.stormcrawler.protocol.okhttp.HttpProtocol"
>    https.protocol.implementation: "com.digitalpebble.stormcrawler.protocol.okhttp.HttpProtocol"
>
> http.proxy.host: localhost
>   http.proxy.port: 9050
>   http.proxy.type: "SOCKS"

Comment: It seem like dont show any error when fetch the page.

fetching http://wikitjerrta4qgz4.onion/ (queue crawl delay=5000ms)
fetching https://laz-img-cdn.alicdn.com (queue crawl delay=5000ms)